# ASP.Net Core multiple-query Get

Tags: c#, query-string, observable, restful-architecture, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working on a simple todo list Api and have a get method that keeps growing with additional optional queries as I expand the functionality of the API. This seems to work fine, but I wanted to know if there is a cleaner way to pass in queries. Currently I have 6 queries, which makes for a long URL and long function definition. Can I somehow pass those as a single object?